# ReactJS "Not a constructor" TypeError (CARTO.JS)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to integrate a CARTO map according to [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqm0j22o38):

Importing Carto:

```
// Import react-leaflet for the map / basemap components
import { Map, TileLayer as Basemap } from 'react-leaflet';

// Import CARTO.js v4 <3
import carto from 'carto.js';

// Import our custom Layer component (it uses carto.js methods internally)
import Layer from './Layer';

// Voyager basemap <3
const CARTO_BASEMAP = 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
```

This is the constructor of my React Component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      center: [40.758313915, -3.67774875],
      zoom: 11,
    },

    // Setup the client in the contructor with our user and apiKey
    this.cartoClient = new carto.Client({ apiKey: 'wadus', username: 'rochoa' });
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "carto.js": "^4.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-simple-storage": "^1.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-connect": "^7.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

When running, receiving:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_carto_js___default.a.Client is not a constructor
```

Having a hard time to understand what is wrong here...

Comment: Can you show the line where you are importing carto? And can you provide the version of `carto.js` you are using?

Comment: Added in the edit. `npm -v carto` gives back 6.2.0

Comment: Can you show the content of your `package.json`?

Comment: added in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because that there are differences between carto.js 4.0.0-beta and 4.0.1.

The example you linked to is using 4.0.0-beta version. I tried created a sandbox with carto.js 4.0.1, and the issue happen as well.

I can't find the documentation about carto.js differences between 4.0.1 and 4.0.0 beta. The [official docs](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/guides/quickstart/) even says that you should do `new cartoClient()` as well. I can only assume that there are something wrong with their 4.0.1 version.

What you can do right now is install the beta package instead of 4.0.1.

```
npm -i carto.js@4.0.0-beta.42
```

Then run your project again.

Comment: uninstalled carto, installed 4.0.0-beta.42, run the project, but still the same typeerror :/

Comment: How about `4.0.0-beta.4` ? Have you rebuild your project?

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately... Did 4.0.0 work for you?

Comment: Yes it did work. Only got `unauthorized` error. Ah, I see you are using `react-leaflet` 2.0.0. Try using `1.7.8` instead. And `leaflet 1.2.0` as well. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The package is outdated. They moved it to another place. I added as dependency @carto/carto.js instead of carto.js and substituted it in whatever file it's used in.

```
npm install @carto/carto.js

import carto from '@carto/carto.js'
```